# Return object(s) in array with highest property value per group

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array containing several objects similar to the following:

```
{person: {name: "Steve", id: 1}, role: 1}
{person: {name: "Phil", id: 2}, role: 1}
{person: {name: "Steve", id: 1}, role: 3}
{person: {name: "Phil", id: 2}, role: 6}
```

My intention is to return an array of the same type, but I'd like to return only one object per "person" with their highest role.

I understand the following will give me a single object with the highest role.

```
array.reduce((prev, cur) => prev.role > cur.role ? prev : cur);
```

How do I return each unique person and their corresponding highest role as a new array?

Like so:

```
{person: {name: "Steve", id: 1}, role: 3}
{person: {name: "Phil", id: 2}, role: 6}
```

Comment: `_.map(_.groupBy(input, 'person.id'), vs => _.maxBy(vs, 'role'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to collect the objects and if you have already one with the same `id` check the `role` and take the greater one.

```js
var data = [{ person: { name: "Steve", id: 1 }, role: 1 }, { person: { name: "Phil", id: 2 }, role: 1 }, { person: { name: "Steve", id: 1 }, role: 3 }, { person: { name: "Phil", id: 2 }, role: 6 }],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var index = r.findIndex(({ person: { id } }) => id === o.person.id);
        if (index === -1) {
            r.push(o);
            return r;
        }
        if (r[index].role < o.role) {
            r[index] = o;
        }
        return r;    
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Group the items by `person.id` with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), but for each `id` store only the object with the highest role. Convert back to array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const data = [{ person: { name: "Steve", id: 1 }, role: 1 }, { person: { name: "Phil", id: 2 }, role: 1 }, { person: { name: "Steve", id: 1 }, role: 3 }, { person: { name: "Phil", id: 2 }, role: 6 }];

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
  const id = o.person.id;
  
  if(!r[id] || r[id].role < o.role) r[id] = o;
  
  return r;
}, []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and build out an object literal like below. Use the `person.name` property value as the object key and then just update the role value if you find a higher value:

```js
var people = [{
  person: {
    name: "Steve",
    id: 1
  },
  role: 1
}, {
  person: {
    name: "Phil",
    id: 2
  },
  role: 1
}, {
  person: {
    name: "Steve",
    id: 1
  },
  role: 3
}, {
  person: {
    name: "Phil",
    id: 2
  },
  role: 6
}];

var highRoleByPerson = people.reduce((accum, el) => {
  if (accum[el.person.name]) {
    if (el.role > accum[el.person.name].role) {
      accum[el.person.name].role = el.role;
    }
  } else {
    accum[el.person.name] = {
      person: {
        name: el.person.name,
        id: el.person.id
      },
      role: 0
    };
  }
  return accum;
}, {});

console.log(highRoleByPerson);
```